# AutoCompleteTextView hint and text design not showing

Tags: android, xml

Here is the code that building Edit text in my XML file you can go through image too that I provided below

```xml
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/from_tv"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:hint="@string/select_country"
    >
    <AutoCompleteTextView

    android:id="@+id/from_auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:text="amirican_dollar"
        />
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Error image:

[image: Error Image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't see any view in design for in Android studio there is probably you written code is not right to initiate view. If you facing issue in hint and text you can use this code snippet.

```
                    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                               >

                        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
                            android:id="@+id/et_username"
                            style="@style/EditText"
                          
                            android:hint="@{String.format(@string/email).toUpperCase()}"
                            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                            android:nextFocusForward="@+id/et_password"
                            android:padding="@dimen/space10"/>
                    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Edit text style in **style.xml** File

```
<style name="EditText">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">@dimen/et_height</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/theme</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/theme_gray1</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/et_text</item>
    <item name="android:imeOptions">actionNext</item>
    <item name="android:maxLines">1</item>
    <item name="android:singleLine">true</item>
    <item name="android:background">@null</item>
    <item name="android:padding">@dimen/space5</item>

    <!--<item name="android:theme">@style/EditText_theme</item>-->
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/font_opensans_regular</item>
</style>
```

In dimen or space is the size in differnt format so you can customize it as per your need. You can use dp for it.